# callback without pointers in C ??? gcc

Tags: c, gcc, callback

```
int compare(int e1, int e2){
    return (e1>e2);}

int mycompare( int e1, int e2, int cmp(int e1, int e2)){
    return cmp(e1,e2);

}
int main()
{
    int a = mycompare(2,1,compare);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does it work? There is no pointers in the "mycompare" definition.

Comment: It's technically a pointer. The syntax allows this.

Comment: Because the language allows it. The pointer syntax for a function pointer formal parameter is optional.

Answer (score 1):

Most know that arrays when declared as parameters get adjusted ("decay") into a pointer to the first element. But there is also a similar, far more exotic rule for functions declared as parameters (C11 6.7.6.3/8):

> A declaration of a parameter as "function returning *type*" shall be adjusted to "pointer to function returning *type*".

So in your example, the code is equivalent to using a function pointer:

```
int mycompare (int e1, int e2, int(*cmp)(int e1, int e2))
```

---

However, please don't use either form! They are simply not very readable. Instead always use a typedef:

```
typedef int cmpfunc (int e1, int e2);
...
int mycompare (int e1, int e2, cmpfunc* cmp);
```